# Copy and delete in c++

Tags: c++

I have class named "Student" with 3 members.

In addition, I have 2 functions, `SetName` and `Operator=`.

```
class Student
{
private:
    int ID;
    char* name;
    Faculty faculty;

public :
bool SetName(const char* other);

};

typedef enum { ENGINEERING, MEDICINE, HUMANITIES, MANAGEMENT, GENERAL } Faculty;


bool Student::SetName(const char * other)
{

    if (!other)
        return false;
    char* temp;
    temp = new char[strlen(other) + 1];
    if (!temp)
        return false;
    //if (this->name)
        //  delete[]name;

    std::string s = other;
    name = temp;
    memcpy(name,other,strlen(other) + 1);


    return true;
}

Student& Student::operator=(const Student &other)
{

    this->ID = other.ID;
    this->faculty = other.faculty;
    this->SetName(other.name);
    return *this;
};
```

Of course, I have default and copy destructor.
There is a problem with the "SetName" Function, but When I run valgrind, it tells me -

```
==4661== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4661==     in use at exit: 72,710 bytes in 2 blocks
==4661==   total heap usage: 47 allocs, 45 frees, 74,410 bytes allocated
==4661== 
==4661== 6 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==4661==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4661==    by 0x402798: Student::SetName(char const*) (in /home/noam/Desktop/Avoda3/temp/myStudentSet)
==4661==    by 0x40264E: Student::Student(Student const&) (in /home/noam/Desktop/Avoda3/temp/myStudentSet)
==4661==    by 0x4011D6: StudentSet::Add(Student const&) (in /home/noam/Desktop/Avoda3/temp/myStudentSet)
==4661==    by 0x400F1D: StudentSet::StudentSet(Student const*, int) (in /home/noam/Desktop/Avoda3/temp/myStudentSet)
==4661==    by 0x4020B6: main (in /home/noam/Desktop/Avoda3/temp/myStudentSet)
==4661== 
==4661== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4661==    definitely lost: 6 bytes in 1 blocks
==4661==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4661==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4661==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==4661==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4661== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==4661== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
```

When I try to remove the comment and add

```
 if (this->name)
        delete[]name;
```

to the `SetName` function, I have much more problems.

I don't have any idea how to solve this.
Can someone help me or give a hint?

Comment: Use `std::string` throughout instead of `char *` and the memory will be taken care of for you by the standard library.

Comment: You should declare in `class Student` the field `std::string name` (instead of `char* name`).

Comment: @cxw Thre is no way to solve it with char* ? For now, i perefer tho use char* insted of String.

Comment: Yuck. Use `std::string`. Using `char*` in C++ is a bit like pushing your car, rather than driving it.

Comment: It would be irresponsible of us to help with that!

Comment: You copy the raw memory of a `std::string` object, which can have any layout and reside in memory offlimits to you,  to `name` - If you really want to use char* then request the strings's internal buffer with the `c_str()` member function. Also, new does not return a `nullptr` when allocation fails but throws `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :) :)  --- Noam, yes, it can absolutely be done with `char *`.  But unless someone is forcing you, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: What do you mean ? @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: Anyway, Noam, welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about the general flow around here.  Good luck!

Comment: Please read about rule of five or even better about rule of zero.

Comment: Telling a beginner that hasn't learned `std::string`, and is just learning the basic with pointers and dynamic memory allocation, to use `std::string` isn't going to be very helpful. I don't think there's anything wrong with trying to implement something simple using `new` and `delete` only. Getting a good grasp, and understanding, and thorough working knowledge of how dynamic allocation works is crucial to obtaining a solid fundamental grasp of C++, and ***then*** forging ahead to using higher-level classes, and such...

Comment: ... anyway, the only code you have that deletes `name` is in `Setname()`. Unless `Setname()` gets called, nothing gets deleted. And if `Setname()` delets the previous `name`, it'll just create a new one instead. That's why valgrind is telling you that you're leaking memory. You need a destructor. And you will also need a copy-constructor and an assignment operator, to make your class [rule 3 compliant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have destructor, this is not problem.
The problem is coming when im trying to delete name is Setname functiom, and im trying to delete it because i want to copy another char * to name.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik He is already using `std::string` as a temporary storage location during his copy.

Comment: @NoamMoscovich It would be quite helpful if you showed us what problems you are seeing when you try to delete the original string. Also, we have no indication that you are initializing `name ` to `nullptr` in the constructor, which could cause your deletion problems.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `new` and `delete` and pointers are **advanced** stuff. `std::string` is **basic**.

Comment: `std::string s = other; what is this doing here?

Comment: If you use `char` arrays in a structure, prefer to have them fixed length.  Fixed length records can be more efficient than variable length, for example, when reading from or writing to files.

Answer (score 3):

> For now, i perefer tho use char*

You should prefer to learn how to use your c++ tools. The first suggestion, use `std::string` would be preferable.

But if you insist on managing memory yourself, you would delete the memory in the class destructor.

```
~Student( ) { delete[ ] name; }
```

That way it survives in whatever scope your class object does. But what if you did not call `SetName(...)`? Then the garbage that name is pointing to is not deletable.

```
class Student
   :name( nullptr )
{
   ~Student( ) { delete[ ] name; }
   ....
```

Now if you don't use SetName(...) you won't be trying to delete something unknown.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the created Student object goes out of scope (is destructed), the allocated memory for the name is not deleted. Add a destructor to your class, init the name pointer to NULL in the constructor and test it in the destructor. If not NULL, delete[] it. Good luck, your code might also need some cleaning up but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with mix of pre-C+11 C++. You need to make sure that constructors, assignment operators and destructor manage the memory correctly. The following code runs under `valgrid` without any leaks:

```
#include <string.h>

typedef enum { ENGINEERING, MEDICINE, HUMANITIES, MANAGEMENT, GENERAL } Faculty;

class Student
{
private:
    int ID;
    char* name;
    Faculty faculty;

public :
    Student() : name(0) {}
    ~Student() {
    if (name)
        delete [] name;
    }
    bool SetName(const char* other);
};

bool Student::SetName(const char * other)
{
    if (!other)
         return false;

    const int len_other_with_null = strlen(other) + 1;
    char *temp = new char[len_other_with_null];

    if (!temp) {
        return false;
    }

    if (this->name)
        delete [] name;

    name = temp;
    memcpy(name, other, len_other_with_null);

    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    Student student;
    student.SetName("Hi");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `delete []` name you was facing is the direct result of *creating a student without a name*.

```
Student student; // student.name is uninitialized. Accessing its value 
                 // would be undefined behaviour.
```

When you try to use `SetName` for the first time, you have an uninitialiised value, and deleting it leads to a crash; so you leave out the `delete[]`, and it leads to a memory leak.

Perhaps you expected to `student.name` to start its life as a null pointer, however this is not how C++ is defined. You must do it yourself.

The idiomatic C++ way is to initialize it in your constructor.

```
 class Student {
  public:
    Student : name(nullptr) {}
    ...
```

Now you can uncomment that `delete`

Let this bug be an important lesson for you. Always write a constructor for your class, and always initialise all data members in it.

Which brings us to the next point. How do you initialize ID and faculty? There are no default "empty" values for them. Even if there were, a student with no ID and no faculty is some kind of ghost we don't want to deal with.

The idiomatic C++ way is to pass these values as parameters to your constructor.

```
 class Student {
  public:
    Student (int ID_, Faculty faculty_) : 
          name(nullptr), ID(ID_), faculty(faculty_) {}
    ..
```

But wait, we have created an unnamed student, which may lead to all kinds of problems down the road. Perhaps pass the name to the constructor too?

```
 class Student {
  public:
    Student (const char* name_, int ID_, Faculty faculty_) :
         name(nullptr), ID(ID_), faculty(faculty_) {
       SetName(name_);
    }
  ...
```

Now this is a student we can be proud of... except for one thing. We can still pass a null pointer as a name, and the student will be left nameless. In `SetName` you deal with it by returning `false` to indicate a failure. Constructors don't return values. What to do?

The idiomatic C++ way is *to throw an exception*.

```
 class Student {
  public:
    Student (const char* name_, int ID_, Faculty faculty_) :
         name(nullptr), ID(ID_), faculty(faculty_) {
       if (!name_)
          throw std::domain_error("Null name passed to Student::Student");
       SetName(name_);
    }
  ...
```

Your class should have a copy constructor according to the rule of three:

```
 class Student {
  public:
    Student(const Student& other) : 
         Student(other.name, other.ID, other.faculty) {}
    Student (const char* name_, int ID_, Faculty faculty_) :
         name(nullptr), ID(ID_), faculty(faculty_) {
       if (!name_)
          throw std::domain_error("Null name passed to Student::Student");
       SetName(name_);
    }
```

Of course in real code you want to use `std::string` rather than manually managing C-style strings.